# Pass "-stdlib=libc++" to c++ linker with autotools

Tags: imagemagick, autotools, configure, libc++, clang++

I'm trying to compile ImageMagick (in particular Magick++) with clang++ and libc++. Therefore I need to pass -stdlib=libc++ to both compiler and linker.

While CXXFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++" works fine for compiling, LDFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++" seems to only affect the C linker.

How to correctly tell ./configure or make to use this flag when linking C++ libraries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use both — CXXFLAGS for the C++ compiler and LDFLAGS for the linker:

```
./configure CXXFLAGS="-O2 -g -stdlib=libc++" LDFLAGS="-stdlib=libc++"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
 LDFLAGS="-Wl,-stdlib=libc++"
```